# Integral of "white noise" multiplied by exponential term (multivariate Ornstein-Uhlenbeck)

Tags: reference-request, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

Consider a matrix differential equation for the vector $\mathbf{y}$ of the form
\begin{equation}
    \dot{\mathbf{y}}(t) = A \, \mathbf{y}(t)  +  \mathbf{b}(t)  \, ,
\end{equation}
where $A$ is a constant square matrix and $\mathbf{b}(t)$ a given time-dependent vector of the same dimension of $\mathbf{y}$.
Now, assume that $\mathbf{b}(t)$ is a "white noise" term such that
$$
\langle b_i(t) \rangle=0 \qquad \langle b_i(t) b_j(t') \rangle = 2 D_{ij} \, \delta(t-t') 
$$

where $D$ is a square, positive definite, "diffusion matrix".
This process is a **multivariate Ornstein–Uhlenbeck process**. Is there some good reference for this kind of problem?

We can formally solve the problem by means of the standard matrix exponentiation, namely
\begin{equation}
    {\mathbf{y}(t) } = e^{A t} \mathbf{y}(0) 
    + e^{A t}  \int_0^t  e^{-A z} \mathbf{b}(z) \, dz  
\end{equation}
Clearly, if $A=0$, we just have the usual Wiener (aka "Brownian") process:
\begin{equation}
    {\mathbf{y}(t) } =  \mathbf{y}(0) 
    +   \int_0^t   \mathbf{b}(z) \, dz  
\end{equation}
and the integral gives us a random variable at time $t$ that is Gaussian with a variance that grows linearly in time $t$. However, I do not know how to deal with the generic integral when $A\neq 0$. References/hints/ideas?

**NOTE:** I wrote the process in the "Langevin" form. It is immediate to interpret it in the Ito's way by saying that $\mathbf{b}dt = d\mathbf{W}$, where $d\mathbf{W}$ is the increment of the associated multivariate Wiener process (i.e. the "white noise" is the formal time derivative of the Wiener process).

***Thanks to the comments I found many references: I added an answer to "close the case" and to list them for the interested ones.***
[This tutorial on stochastic calculus](https://inc.ucsd.edu/mplab/75/media/sde.pdf) ("Tutorial on Stochastic Differential Equations" by J. R. Movellan) has been proved to be very useful, clear and to the point.

Comment: just to questions, what's $B_{ij}$ and the  delta function is a dirac's delta? namely the variance of your white noise if infinite?

Comment: No it's the standard "physicist" notation, see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Langevin_equation See e.g. the section "Itô calculus for physicists" here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%C3%B4_calculus . In brief: $b$ is the "time derivative" of the standard  Weiner process $W(t)$: $b(t)dt = dW(t)$

Comment: @Chaos : what I am saying is also explained here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2359361/532409 (my $b(t)$ is the $\xi_t$ appearing there). Using the $\xi_t$ in place of $W_t$ is considered "non-rigorous", but it's just a matter of language: I may recast my question to follow the "rigorous" notation with $W_t$.

Comment: It is a multivariate Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process.

Comment: And also you argument on the distribution doesn't change too much. In 1d case the Ito-Integral $\int_{0}^{t}e^{as}b(s)ds$ is zero-mean Gaussian with variance $\int_{0}^{t}e^{2as}ds$. In the multivariate case it's similar but tediuous.

Comment: Hi @Tobsn, thanks a lot! Do you know some simple reference on this process? Possibly with the proof of your statement. If you can indicate me a couple of good references, you may write an answer out of your comments. Thanks again!

Comment: I found this nice lecture: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qdbkvD4N-us&ab_channel=MITOpenCourseWare at minute 14.00 the 1d Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process is introduced and then analyzed.

Comment: I believe the multivariate ornstein uhlenbeck process will be discussed at length in Gardiner 1983 "Handbook of stochastic methods in the physical sciences".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I was directed in the right direction by the useful comments of @Tobsn, I found nice answers [here](https://quant.stackexchange.com/q/53212) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/809970/532409), see also [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/297882/532409) interesting related question.

**Solution in the 1D case:** this case is simple and can be immediately understood in terms of [Ito's isometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%C3%B4_isometry). Direct application of this general result gives exactly the solution proposed by @Tobsn in the comments.

**Solution for the multivariate case:** thanks to the comment of @kevinkayaks, I found the full solution to all my doubts in section *"4.4.6 Multivariate Ornstein-Uhlenbeck Process"* of *"Handbook of Stochastic Methods"* by Gardiner. I checked many references and this stands out for clarity.

Alternatively, "[Alternative way to derive the distribution of the multivariate Ornstein–Uhlenbeck process](https://advancesindifferenceequations.springeropen.com/articles/10.1186/s13662-019-2214-1)" is about the PDF of the Multivariate Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process. An even better, and very clear, reference is "[Fast Bayesian inference of the multivariate Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process](https://journals.aps.org/pre/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevE.98.012136)".